# How do I display the objects inside a useState state in the return?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

```js
import React, { useState , useEffect} from 'react';

function Counter(){
    const targetDate = '1 Jan 2023';
    const target = new Date(targetDate);
    const currDate = new Date();

    const targetTime = target.getTime();
    const currDateTime = currDate.getTime();

    const time = targetTime - currDateTime;

    var seconds = Math.floor((time % (1000*60)) / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor((time % (1000*60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var hours = Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (100 * 60 * 60));
    var days = Math.floor(time / (1000*60*60*24));

    const [ctime , setCTime] = useState({seconds , minutes , hours , days});

    useEffect(() =>{
        const interval = setInterval(() => setCTime(ctime) , 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    })
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Countdown</h1>
            {ctime}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Counter;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This is my code up to this point, I have all the values I need to display calculating as I want them, but since I'm learning hooks and how to use them, I cant figure out how to display the values from the state.

The error I'm getting is "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, minutes, hours, days}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: Use JSON.stringify(ctime) or ctime.seconds or some other unit to display its value, react doesn't renders objects directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that you want to make a countdown timer. And I wrote similar with suitable react codes.

```
function Counter() {
  // initial state is 0 for all
  const [ctime, setCTime] = useState({
    seconds: 0,
    minutes: 0,
    hours: 0,
    days: 0,
  });

  // Do not use global variables if you don't need to
  const startCountDown = () => {
    const targetTime = new Date("1 Jan 2023").getTime();
    const currDateTime = new Date().getTime();
    const time = targetTime - currDateTime;

    const s = Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    const m = Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    const h = Math.floor((time % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (100 * 60 * 60));
    const d = Math.floor(time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    setCTime({ seconds: s, minutes: m, hours: h, days: d });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => startCountDown(), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Countdown</h1>
      <div>
        {ctime.days}:{ctime.hours}:{ctime.minutes}:{ctime.seconds}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering the direct object `ctime`. You need to render the properties.

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Countdown</h1>
    {ctime.seconds}
    {ctime.minutes}
    {ctime.hours}
    {ctime.days}
  </div>
);
```